# python tuple in sql string

Tags: python, sql, tuples

I have a sql query like this:

```sql
"...AND A IN (12,13,14)..."
```

now I want to replace the (12,13,14) with a python tuple that may contain far more than 3 three elements.

In Matlab, I can simply write

```matlab
'AND A IN',my_tuple,
```

How can I achieve the same result in python?

Comment: `.replace("(12,13,14)", "(...)")`?..

Comment: the "(12,13,14)" here is just a demo example, no practical use. What I need is "... AND A IN tuple...", and tuple can be (12,13,14...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `f-string` for simplicity:

```
t = ('1','2','3')
sql_string = f"SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE A IN ({','.join(t)})"
print(sql_string) # SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE A IN (1,2,3)
```

**BUT**: In case you use any kind of DBAPI use their build in Bind-Parameter logic and avoid concatinating your own SQL-Queries to avoid SQL-Injection etc...

**AND**: most databases limit the amount of values you can put into an `IN(...)` clause, for example Oracle only allows 1000 values

Answer (score 0):

my_tuple = (1,2,5,15)
sql_string = 'select * from table where A IN ' + my_tuple

something like this?

Post more more lines of your code if you need a better answer.

Comment: I am actually trying to concatenate a tuple with the rest part of my SQL query. Your suggestion gives the error "can only concatenate str(not "tuple") to str".